# How to create new instance of class in laravel through variable name?

Tags: laravel

I'm creating an API which passes me the model name as parameter. So what I want is to create a new instance of that model class and get the required data accordingly. The error which I am facing right now is that it is not generating the namespace even though I have added the model use above. I tried adding "" before the variable new but still didn't work. Also I tried **ReflectionClass** to initialize class instance but still it is not finding the class. I'd be really grateful if someone can help me out here.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- if you already imported it using `use` at the top than you dont need to put `"\\"` use

```
new $className
```

- else simply use the full namespace `'App\\Models\\'.$className` ( without Models for laravel 7- )

```
new 'App\\Models\\'.$className
```

[image]

Edit : added `\\` for not escaping `'` you can added it only before the `'` didnt cause an issue in the code i showed because there is no `\` right before the `'`

Comment: well it's still not working because each model is inside different folders.

Comment: I did tried it without the \\ but still it's not finding the class.

Comment: thats a different issue ! ig you need to import them all and use classNames directly but thats not really good . i would suggest you make all models under the same namespace in this case .

Comment: Well i just passed the whole address of class with model_type param.

Comment: if you can adjust the params thats better , but i dont recommand passing the namespace like that . provide more info next time about the issue .

Answer (score 0):

You must use complete namespace:

```
$class = 'App\'.$className
```

Comment: Well i can't because their are different model inside different folders so the namespace will be different.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct code of snippet you've added.

And it should work with full namespace path:

```php
if($request->has('model_type')){
  $class = '\\App\\Models\\' . (string) $request->model_type;
  
  return new $class;
}
```

Comment: But it's inside different folders

Answer (score 0):

Just give full path of your Model class as below:

```
$className = $request->model_type;
$class_path = 'App\\'.$className; // take  a full path of your Model class.
$class = new $class_path;

return $class;
```

Comment: but each model is inside different path.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I believe the answers posted already are pretty good to resolve your issue.

Nonetheless, I personally feel that you're doing it the wrong way.

1. You would **rarely** need to pass *model names* in your 'API' routes.

**Why?** - This would essentially lead to a *tight coupling* between your route parameters and your *model names*. This forces you to change your *"route signature"* whenever you change your model names.

2. You typically are expected to use *'id'/'slug'/'custom column'* (preferably a primary key) to allow you to identify your models. i.e:

Ex 1: [Resource Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) `api/events/{event}/tickets/{ticket}`

Ex 2: [Customizing The Key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name)
`api/posts/{post:slug}`

With this approach:

A. You can make use of [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding).

B. You immediately know which route parameter corresponds with which model. i.e:

```php
// use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// use App\Models\Event;
// use App\Models\Ticket;
// Incase you use 'id' as you model's primary key.
function update(Request $request, $event, $ticket)
{
    $eventModel = Event::find($event);
    $ticketModel = Ticket::find($ticket);
}
```

Lastly, You can still quite easily validate route parameters since they are also *part* of the `Request` object. i.e:

```php
$request->validate([
    "event" => "required|numeric|exists:events",
    "ticket" => "required|numeric|exists:tickets",
]);
```